# Creating text images with php

Tags: php, image, imagettftext

I am using the following code:

```
<?php
 $im = ImageCreate(350, 70);
 $white = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF);
 $fontColor = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0xF2,0x67,0x22);
 ImageTTFText ($im, 20, 0, 10, 40, $fontColor, '/home/squareli/public_html/cookingessence.com/fonts/TektonPro-BoldExt.otf', $text); 
 Header('Content-Type: image/png');
 ImagePNG($im);
?>
```

I want to take this code and save it in its own .php file. I want to than be able to access this file through other pages on my site. I want to assign $text different variables for each page. Is this possible?

I currently am able to access the php code through other pages using:

```
<img src="code-page-name.php">
```

My issue is I can not find a way to assign a variable for $text. The only way I have been able to do it is by putting the name directly into the above code or loading the specific page and adding the variable in the URL /code-page-name.php?text=Name%On%The%Page

Answer (score 0):

you can send the text through get.

```
code-page-name.php?text=blah
```

than you can access it so

```
$_GET[text]
```

What ever you send in the url can be access through $_GET and you can send more than one variable. For example `code-page-name.php?text=blah&color=red&color2=green` etc.

Comment: I had tried this and was unable to get it to work. No text shows up just a white background, so the variable is not going through.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use sessions. It will be something like captcha. You can work with $text as variable and will have it written as image at one time.

```
#file1.php
session_start();
$text = $_SESSION['text'];
//draw the image here

#file2.php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['text'];
```

Comment: Session is not a good idea since it is not reliable and it can disappear at anytime. If you really want to use sessions, save it in db. I always have bad experience with sessions.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. I get the following error:

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at public_html/template.php:17) in public_html/inc/index.inc.php on line 2. 

Line 2 is: session_start();

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. It got ride of the error but the text still won't display.

Answer (score 0):

Of cause `$_SESSION` is not reliable. But it's the best and easiest solution.

**code-page-name.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["text"])) {
$text = $_SESSION["text"];
}
else {
$text = "Default Text";
}
$im = ImageCreate(350, 70);
$white = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF);
$fontColor = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0xF2,0x67,0x22);
ImageTTFText ($im, 20, 0, 10, 40, $fontColor, '/home/squareli/public_html/cookingessence.com/fonts/TektonPro-BoldExt.otf', $text);
Header('Content-Type: image/png');
ImagePNG($im);
?>
```

**other-page-name.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["text"] = "WhatEver";
?>
<img src="code-page-name.php" />
```

Remember to put `session_start()` function before any html tag.